# How to change the hover color of Material-UI table?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using React and [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/) for my web application. I want to change the hover color of table row but cannot do that.

Sample code:

```
x={
  hover:{
    color:'green'
  }
}

<TableRow
  hover
  key={lead.id} className={classes.row}
  classes={{
    hover:x.hover
  }}
  onClick={() => {}}
>
```

Answer (score 17):

I've got this solution so far. Maybe there are other approaches to override css of tableRow but this one works like a charm:

```
const styles = theme => ({
tableRow: {
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "blue !important"
    }
  }
});


<TableRow hover
      key={lead.id} className={classes.tableRow}

      onClick={() => {}}>
```

Feel free to ask any question.

Comment: Thanks Mansoor, this I know, looking something more of material ui way or something directly in theme. And +1 from me as I missed possible solution and what I tried in my question.

Comment: I'm geeting this with your code: 
```Material-UI: the key `tableRow` provided to the classes property is not implemented in TableRow.
You can only override one of the following: root,selected,hover,head,footer```

In order to avoid this should change "tableRow" to "hover" and don't forget !importante, here is the key. THX

Comment: please share your code in codesandbox. It's easier to debug

Answer (score 11):

This is a trivial task in **MUI v5**. See the docs [here](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#palette):

```
<Table
  sx={{
    "& .MuiTableRow-root:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "primary.light"
    }
  }}
>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 6):

Just in case, if you are using the component overrides and want to do a style override you have to target the root and not the hover rule. I spent quite a while trying to get the pseudo :hover to work on that but it wouldn't ever work.

Here's what I have.

```
MuiTableRow: {
    styleOverrides: {
        // Even though there is a hover rule we have to override it here. Don't ask.
        root: {
            '&.MuiTableRow-hover:hover': {
                backgroundColor: 'blue',
            },
        },
    },
},
```

Use this is you want to override the component at the theme level vs styled overrides, sx or useStyles.

Comment: This is the correct answer now that Mui exists, Though `'&:hover'` is enough

Comment: +1. Problem is it applies "hover" on header row as well. Would be nice to see background changes on rows in body only. Any hints?

Answer (score 5):

```
tableRow: {
    hover: {
        "&$hover:hover": {
            backgroundColor: '#49bb7b',
        },
    },
}

<TableRow className={classes.tableRow} key={n.id} hover onClick={event => this.handleClick(event)}>Text</TableRow>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to that code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 5):

just put hover in the TableRow, but not the header Tablerow

```
 <StyledTableRow hover key={row.name}>
```

@material-ui/core/TableRow has built in code to deal with hover, it worked for me.

Comment: Yes, just add `hover` to the TableRow: `<TableRow hover>`

Answer (score 5):

The [implementation of the TableRow component](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/TableRow/TableRow.js) and the [customizing components page](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#use-rulename-to-reference-a-local-rule-within-the-same-style-sheet) show that you need to override two classes, root.hover:hover and .hover to change the hover color.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  /* Styles applied to the root element. */
  root: {
    // Default root styles
    color: 'inherit',
    display: 'table-row',
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    // We disable the focus ring for mouse, touch and keyboard users.
    outline: 0,

    '&$hover:hover': {
      // Set hover color
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.hover,
    },
  },

  /* Pseudo-class applied to the root element if `hover={true}`. */
  hover: {},
}));
```

Then in your component, you can apply the styles to the classes prop.

```
const HelloWorld = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <TableRow classes={classes}><TableCell></TableCell></TableRow>
  );
};
```

Comment: preferred for using/showing the variable and not using `!important`

Comment: Using the theme.palette.action.hover property is by far the best answer instead of a hardcoded value.

Answer (score 4):

You can maintain dependency on the Material UI hover prop by using

```
hover: {
  '&:hover': {
    backgroundColor: 'green !important',
  },
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually a better approach to working with MUI than adding per-component overrides is to find which theme variable is responsible for the effect we want to achieve and override that variable.

It's very likely your table rows, list items, menu items and others should all have consistent hover background color. If that's the case, you could override `palette.action.hover`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using withstyles you can just override it in the root element like so:

An example of how to do it is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/7249117670

Answer (score 0):

```
const theme = createTheme({
    components: {
        MuiTableRow: {
            styleOverrides: {
                root: {
                    '&:hover': {
                        backgroundColor: 'blue'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Worked like a charm for   "@mui/material": "^5.8.7",